# Why isnt anything showing up?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am creating a mutli color circle border using arcs, but I am not seeing anything in the view. I am using this question as [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439865/how-to-make-dynamical-strokecolor-in-cashapelayer-in-swift). To check the arc class look at the link I provided. If the number at indexPath.item is greater than .69, I need an arc from 0 to .69 in red and the rest orange. By rest I mean the percentage in the array. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (number[indexPath.item] >= 0.70 ){

        let arc = Arc()

         let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(cell.progress.frame.width / 2, cell.progress.frame.height / 2), radius: CGFloat(60), startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2 * numbers[indexPath.item] - M_PI_2), clockwise: true)

        arc.addFigure(circlePath.CGPath, fillColor: UIColor.clearColor(), strokeColor: UIColor.redColor(), strokeStart: 0.0, strokeEnd: CGFloat(0.69), lineWidth: 5.0, miterLimit: 0.0, lineDashPhase: 0.0, layer: cell.progress.layer)

        arc.addFigure(circlePath.CGPath, fillColor: UIColor.clearColor(), strokeColor: UIColor.orangeColor(), strokeStart: CGFloat(0.69), strokeEnd: CGFloat(numbers[indexPath.item]), lineWidth: 5.0, miterLimit: 0.0, lineDashPhase: 0.0, layer: cell.progress.layer)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath



        //shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        //shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        //shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0

        //cell.progress.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues here:

1. For `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd`, you appear to doing radian angle calculations for a circular bezier curve, but that's not how `addFigure` is using these parameters. It's handing these off to the eponymous `CAShapeLayer` properties, and those go from `0` to `1`, not `0` to `M_PI * 2.0`.
2. The `addFigure` is creating a `CAShapeLayer`, but you're not doing anything with the `return` value. I would have thought that you'd add the resulting `CAShapeLayer` as `sublayer` or something like that.

Comment: So I understand how to fix number one but how would I fix number 2?

Comment: You're creating three shape layers here, one in each of `addFigure` calls, and another right here in the code in this question. I assume you want to take the result of each call to `addFigure` and add both as sublayers. And then this third `CAShapeLayer` seems entirely redundant to me, so I'd be inclined to get rid of that entirely, unless there was something else you were attempting to accomplish there.

Comment: That makes more sense, but I am still a little lost. So you are saying that the `let shapeLayer = ...` and below is redundant, and should be deleted? If so how would I add the arcs to the view?

Comment: `let shapeLayer1 = arc.addFigure(...))` and then add that `shapeLayer1` as a sublayer. Then repeat that for the second call to `addFigure`. Again, the poorly named `addFigure` method is returning a `CAShapeLayer` (though it didn't add it to anything). So take that shape layer that was returned, and do something with it (e.g. add it as a sublayer).